# Redis set of sets - Is there a better Design?

Tags: design, redis

I have a telegram bot that alerts whenever a price of certain asset reach a certain price.

I have the following table in a DB:

- AlertId
- ChatId
- Price
- Asset

So each Asset will have several ChatId (users) and each of them can have several AlertId, and AlertID is a unique autonumeric value.

As this data is constantly read, I decided to cache it using Redis.

I ended up with the following Redis design, but I'm not really confortable with it, I feel there's a better way to design it.

I made 2 sets:

`Asset:{asset}`- return lists of ChatId that have alerts on that Asset

`ChatId:{chatId}` - return lists of AlertId

and the following key that contains the price

`Alerts:{alertId}` - returns JSON with price that will trigger the alarm.

To send the alert via Telegram I need the chatId, the asset and the price, so for each price update I make the following algorithm:

- check if there's any item in `Asset:{asset}`
- enter a for loop with previous values for ChatId
- loop again for each ChatId and check if the condition for the price is reached
- alert accordingly
- delete the record from db and from Redis

Is this design ok? or is there a better feature from Redis that I'm missing? The whole "set inside a set" makes some noise inside my head, but maybe this is the way it is suppoused to be used. This is my first time designing a solution using Redis.

Thank you very much,